# How to create a many to many relationship with latest nightly builds of EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

How do you use the Fluent API to create a many to many relationship between two tables in <strike>EF7</strike> EF Core?  For example, say you have the following tables:

[image: Photos to People database diagram]

How would one leverage the modelBuilder in the DbContext class to define a relationship like this?

I've seen [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes---July-31,-2014) link from the EF team's meeting notes regarding this subject, but it is from last year and am wondering if there is new information on how to approach this in <strike>EF7</strike> EF Core.

I am able to create one to many relationships between Photos and PhotosPeople as well as People and PhotosPeople.  The database is generated as I'd like it to be, but the navigation between People and Photos now requires interaction with an intermediate entity.  I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is tracked by [#1368](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1368). The workaround is to map the join table to an entity:

```cs
class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonPhoto> PersonPhotos{ get; set; }
}

class PersonPhoto
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonPhoto> PersonPhotos{ get; set; }
}
```

Be sure to configure `PersonPhoto` with a composite key:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhoto>().HasKey(x => new { x.PhotoId, x.PersonId });
}
```

To navigate, use a Select:

```cs
// person.Photos
var photos = person.PersonPhotos.Select(c => c.Photo);
```

Comment: When I try to run the migration it says: Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata.ModelItemNotFoundException: The entity type 'PersonPhoto' requires a key to be defined.

Comment: Hence my note in the code. Configure it using `modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhoto>().Key(x => new { x.PhotoId, x.PersonId });`

Comment: Ohh. Great. Thanks bricelam. Sorry for not paying attention. Thanks.

Comment: @bricelam, I'm having some trouble in Asp.Net 5 when trying this approach, following your exmaple, apparently if I try to return a JSON of a Person with her Photos I got no response because it falls in a forever loop of references between Person, and the PersonPhotos collection, have any way to solve this situation?

Comment: @bricelam this approach worked fine for me when I'm adding the entity, but I had to write all the logic for adding and removing the rows on the join table while updating. Is there an easiest way to update? Thanks in advance

Comment: @bricelam, I am using EF7. I tried to follow your example and created a composite key, but it returned me an error - EntityTypeBuilder<T> does not contain a definition for 'Key' or extension method 'Key'. Did it require any other reference?

Comment: @seanbun I believed the method was renamed to `HasKey` (to match EF6)

Comment: Let's say you have a person and you want to assign a list of photos to the person. How do you go about this?

Comment: @Riscie See the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) article in the EFCore documentation for other types of relationships.

Comment: @bricelam I have a many-to-many relationship like described here. I don't understand how I can make multiple connections between the two entities at once. Like when I have a `Person` and a list of `Photos` (like in the example above), how can I create the mapping-entities of type `PersonPhoto` all at once?

Comment: @Riscie Ah, I see. You'll need two association classes. (e.g. `PersonTaggedInPhoto` and `PersonLikesPhoto`)