# EF7: Foreign Keys are not generated when adding to Database Context

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta3 and am trying to create a many-to-many relationship between two tables. For that I'm using the syntax from [The answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-latest-nightly-builds-of-ef7), minus the ICollections:

```
public class Permissions
{
    public Guid PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class relUserPermissions
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Guid PermissionId { get; set; }
    public Permissions Permission { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationUser` is referring to the `AspNetUsers` Table. Using the kpm migration tool, this will create the `relUserPermissions` Table with foreign keys to both `AspNetUsers` and `Permissions`.

As I'm trying to access this via LINQ, I need to add the relation to the Database Context, using `public DbSet<relUserPermissions> relUserPermission { get; set; }`. But once I add that line, the foreign key to `Permissions` is no longer generated, the foreign key to `AspNetUsers` still is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is a bit annoying, having to do that, for now I was able to solve the problem by renaming `Permissions.PermissionId` to `Permissions.Id`. Not a great solution and I have no clue why this affects anything (I added `PermissionId` as a key via Fluent API before), but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For creating relationship you have to provide it on both the table,

try this:

```
public class Permissions
{
    public Guid PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<relUserPermissions> relUserPermission {get; set;}
}
public class relUserPermissions
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Guid PermissionId { get; set; }
    public Permissions Permission { get; set; }
}
```

add this property in Permissions class

```
public Ilist<relUserPermisions> relUserPermission {get; set;}
```

Comment: I already tried that, with ICollection instead of Ilist. Did not work. I found a workaround in the meantime though.

Answer (score 0):

Add Navigation property as shown bleow

```
public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
public Guid PermissionId { get; set; }
public Permissions Permission { get; set; }
public virtual Permissions Permission { get; set; }
```