# Entity framework 7 relationships (friends of person and group of friends)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm playing and Learning EntityFramework 7 RC1.

I have

```
public class Person
{
  public long PersonId{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Relation> Friends {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Group> Groups{get;set;} //Works if commented
}

public class Relation
{
        public long RelationId { get; set; }
        public long PersonId { get; set; }

        public Person FriendWith { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RelationType> Status { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
        public long GroupId { get; set; }
        public long PersonId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Person> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works in my model but not the last property of the Group class.

What i want is that a person can have Friends(Person) and can group his friends in groups (coworkers, friends...).
The top would be to have the possibility to query a Person and get :
- Person.Friends
- Person.Groups
- Person.Groups.FirstOrDefault().Friends

Thank you very for your help.

Comment: What do you meant with not working? Do you get compilation error?, runtime exception? What do they state?

Comment: Looks like a many-to-many relationship. That's a bit odd in EF7, so you'll have to follow the directions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/

Comment: @E-Bat : The navigation Groups' on entity type 'Person' has not been added to the model, or ignored, or target entityType ignored.

Comment: @JonTheMon : Is it not a One-to-Many Relationship ? And not between photo and person but person and person

Comment: Why do you have a PersonId in the Group?

Comment: @kristen g : as in the ef7 doc (and in Relation). It does not generate any error.The error is Group.Friends. I think i missed Something in the modelBuilder but i don't know what.

Comment: `Person` has collection navigation `Groups` and `Group` has collection navigation `Friends` so it is many to many relationship. A person can have multiple groups and a group can have multiple persons in it. So you need to configure a join table as in the link posted by @JonTheMon. In the absence of which there will not be any relation between `Person` & `Group` therefore EF throws exception that you have navigation properties in the model which are not added to the model.

Comment: EF7 doesn't support Many to Many relationships yet.

Comment: [Same problem is solved in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527336/the-navigation-on-entity-type-has-not-been-added-to-the-model-or-ignored-or-en)