# The navigation on entity type has not been added to the model, or ignored, or entityType ignored

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dnx, entity-framework-core

> The navigation 'Tags' on entity type 'Notepad.Models.Note' has not been added to the model, or ignored, or entityType ignored.

```
public class Note
    {
        public Note()
        {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
            Parts = new HashSet<Part>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    }


public class Tag
    {
        public Tag()
        {
            Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

It happens while adding a migration:

> dnx ef migrations add DbData -c DataDbContext

Why do you think it happens?

EDIT:
DataDbContext:

```
public class DataDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code for `Tag`

Comment: Have you added DbSet<Tag> to DataDbContext?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki I've pasted it to the question, you can see if everything is correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have **Many-to-many** relationship there. As the documentation says: http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#id21

*Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.*

So you must create additional "join" class like this:

```
public class NoteTag
    {
        public int NoteId { get; set; }
        public Note Note { get; set; }

        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

then, replace

```
 ICollection<Tag> Tags {set;get}
```

in your Note class to

```
 ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags {set;get}
```

and also in Tag class:

```
ICollection<Note> Notes {set;get;}
```

to

```
ICollection<NoteTags> NoteTags {set;get}
```

and then override OnModelCreating method in DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<NoteTag>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.NoteId, t.TagId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<NoteTag>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Note)
                .WithMany(p => p.NoteTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.NoteId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<NoteTag>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                .WithMany(t => t.NoteTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
        }
```

Comment: thanks, it seems like migration has been done successfully. But it is very strange, I'm sure that I could do many to many relationships before in entity framework

Comment: @Ludwik11 Yes in EF6 but not EF7, also just stumpled over this error and thought why does another N to M work I have here, then I realized its two 1 to N with a bridge table because that table has a additional property!

Answer (score 2):

I am using EF 7, this problem took around 2 hours of my week end. :)
So, here is the simple solution -
I am having a profile class like this -

```
[Table("Profile")]
public class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {

    }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Key]        
    public Guid ProfileID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<StudentLivingWith> StudentProfileMap { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<StudentLivingWith> ParentProfileMap { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the ProfileID as a F-Key reference in my another table named "StudentLivingWith". (ya, I know the name is bit strange. :)) As you can see in below class, both the columns "StudentProfileID" and "ParentProfileID" refering to the same column "profileID" of my "Profile" table.

```
[Table("StudentLivingWith")]
public class StudentLivingWith
{
    public StudentLivingWith()
    {

    }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StudentLivingWithID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("StudentProfileID")]
    public Guid StudentProfileID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [ForeignKey("ParentProfileID")]
    public Guid ParentProfileID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [InverseProperty("StudentProfileMap")]
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> StudentProfile { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [InverseProperty("ParentProfileMap")]
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> ParentProfile { get; set; }
}
```

So the conclusion is - you just need to add [InverseProperty] tag on the reference, and this simple solution did the trick for me.

I hope this will help. Thanks.