# Saving Many to Many relationship data on ASP.NET MVC6 EF7 Create view

Tags: asp.net, many-to-many, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am new to web app development. I am using ASP.NET MVC6 EF7 to create simple app that provides a set of questions to the user, these questions are served on Pages. For reuse, the pages and questions need to have a many-many relationship.

The model (I am developing code-first) is setup as described in the responses to the other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-latest-nightly-builds-of-ef7) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527336/the-navigation-on-entity-type-has-not-been-added-to-the-model-or-ignored-or-en).

```
// Data Model
public class Page
{
  public int PageID { get; set; } // Key
}
public class Question
{
  Public int QID { get; set; } // Key
  Public string Text { get; set; } // The question
}
public class PQJoin
{
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public virtual Page page { get; set; }

    public int QID { get; set; }
    public virtual Question question { get; set; }
}
```

EF Scaffolded CRUD code was used as a starting point.

I would like to link multiple questions to a page when I set it up.  In the PagesController:

```
ViewData["QuestionsID"] = new MultiSelectList(_context.Question, "QID", "Text");
```

and in the Razor file i create the listbox as follow:

```
@Html.ListBox("QuestionsID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So far so good.  Problem is I am not sure how to return the newly selected questions from the view and correctly populate the `PQJoin` table. What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need a link from Page to PQJoin to Question.

Add this to Page and Question class:

```
public IList<PQJoin> PQJoins {get;set;}
```