# MVC binding products to orders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a prolem with understanding binding process in mvc. So what i got is 3 database tables: Orders, Products, PreOrders. I want to bind the same product for many orders. Right now i have something like this in Order model (i will save the Products as collection in there):

```
public virtual ICollection<Products> Product { get; set; }
```

And the saving goes like this:

```
List<Products> productList = new List<Products>();
 foreach (int list in preOrderList)
            {
                var order = new Orders()
                {
                    //Product = (from item in )
                };

            var orderResult = _context.PreOrder.Single(o => o.Id == list);
            orderResult.Send = true;

            var productResult = _context.Products.Single(p => p.Id == orderResult.ProductId);
            var newProduct = new Products();
            newProduct.Name = productResult.Name;
            newProduct.Price = productResult.Price;
            productList.Add(newProduct);
            OrderList.Add(orderResult);
        }

        var orders = new Orders()
        {
            Product = productList
        };

        _context.Orders.Add(orders);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

With this code i create another product but what i need is bind products to this order and afterwards add the same products to another order. Is it possible?

P.S.

I tried to add the exsisting product:

```
productList.Add(productResult);
```

But in result i can only assign each product one time.

Comment: "But in result i can only assign each product one time." - Could you elaborate?

Comment: public virtual ICollection<Products> Product { get; set; } 
creates virtual OrdersId which is assigned in Products model. So if i create order with corresponding product OrdersId is set and afterwards if i create another order, it is set to new OrdersId.

Answer (score 0):

This is an EF question not an MVC one.

Your products class needs a navigator to orders as well so its a many-many relationship going both ways. Currently you have a one-many from Orders to products and a one-one from Products to Orders.

in Products

```
public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
```

What I assume you have is something like this

```
public class Orders
{
    [key]
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Products> Product { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    [key]
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey]
    public OrderId {get;set;}//remove this
    public virtual Orders Order {get;set;}//replace with ICollection<Orders>
}
```

It is also possible using fluent like so

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>()
            .HasMany<Product>(s => s.Products)
            .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("OrderId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("ProductId");
                        cs.ToTable("TABLENAMEFORRELATIONALTABLE");
                    });

}
```

Comment: It will not work. Tried it receved internal server error.

Comment: Details?
You'll have run your migrations again if using code first.

Comment: If i do that i receve error message: 
The navigation "Product" on entry type "blah blah" has not been added to the model, or ignored, or target entityType igonered.

Product:
public ICollection<Products> Product { get; set; }

Comment: If you don't care about having a navigator from product to orders you can actually remove both the OrderId and virtual orders from the product class altogether and it should work. 
This article will explain a few ways to do what you want.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

I also updated the answer a bit

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

If you are on EF7 try this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527336/the-navigation-on-entity-type-has-not-been-added-to-the-model-or-ignored-or-en/34527818