# Navigation Properties in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework core. I want to have 3 tables: Appoitments, Users and Roles. The 'Users' table contains application members with different roles. Is there a way to have 'Appoitments' table with foreign keys: ClientID and ConsultantID of type 'User'?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ConsultantId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

I created classes ApplicationUser and Appointment and in ApplicationDbContext i added property:
    public DbSet Appointments { get; set; }.

But when I tried to add migration, Packet Manager threw "(Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ApplicationUser.Appointments' of type 'List'.

Comment: Yes, I don't see why there couldn't be?  What have you tried?  Has anything gone wrong?

Comment: Better you go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: I created classes ApplicationUser and Appointment and in ApplicationDbContext i added property:
public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }.

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438052/many-to-many-relation-between-identity-and-custom-table-ef7-code-first)

Comment: Create two collection navigation properties and map them to to corresponding reference navigation property. Also it's good to strip `Id` from the navigation property name. e.g. `ApplicationUser.ClientAppointments` -> `Appointment.Client` and `Application.User.ConsultantAppointments` -> `Appointment.Consultant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough information in the question to **really** distinguish what is going on.. but I don't see why something like this wouldn't work:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Consultant")]
    public int ConsultantId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }


    public ApplicationUser Consultant { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }
}
```