# Entity Framework Core - IN clause equivalent

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I wonder how to convert this sql query to an entity framework query.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Post
WHERE PostId IN (
SELECT PostId FROM BlogPost
WHERE BlogId = &blogId);
```

I am trying to get a list of Posts with a given category id.

Database simplified:

Blog (the category for the post):

```
BlogId
Title
..
```

Post:

```
PostId
Title
..
```

BlogPost for combining the two tables and letting you have multiple categories per post:

```
PostId
BlogId
```

This is what I already have, but ofcourse the query is not working:

```c#
public async Task<IActionResult> Category(int? id)
{
     int blogId = id;

     if (blogId == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }
     ICollection<Post> posts = await _context.Post.Where(pid => pid.PostId.Contains(_context.BlogPost.Where(i => i.PostId == blogId).ToListAsync())).ToListAsync();

     if (posts == null)
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     return View(posts );
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in one query based on the information you provided.

```c#
var posts = await _context.Post
    .Where(post =>
        _context.BlogPost.Any(bp => bp.BlogId == blogId && bp.PostId == post.PostId)
    )
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here is how I would do it in two queries in order to use `Contains` based on the information you provided.

```c#
var postIds = await _context.BlogPost
    .Where(bp => bp.BlogId = blogId)
    .Select(bp => bp.PostId)
    .ToArrayAsync();
var posts = await _context.Post
    .Where(p => postIds.Contains(p.PostId))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here is how I would do it in one query if I were using valuable EntityFramework features, and I had a reference property named Post on BlogPost.

```c#
var posts = await _context.BlogPost
    .Where(bp => bp.BlogId == blogId)
    .Select(bp => bp.Post)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Here is how I would do it in one query if I were using valuable EntityFramework features, and I had a collection property named Posts from Blog, and the many-many BlogPost table was hidden by EntityFramework in such a way that you never actually interact with it from C#.

```c#
var posts = await _context.Blog
    .Where(b => b.BlogId == blogId)
    .SelectMany(b => b.Posts)
    .ToListAsync();
```

On the other hand if the many-many BlogPost table is exposed by EntityFramework then you could still start at the Blog and use properly configured collection and reference properties to get to the posts like so.

```c#
var posts = await _context.Blog
    .Where(b => b.BlogId == blogId)
    .SelectMany(b => b.BlogPosts)
    .Select(bp => bp.Post)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Or

```c#
var posts = await _context.Blog
    .Where(b => b.BlogId == blogId)
    .SelectMany(b => b.BlogPosts.Select(bp => bp.Post))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Takeaway, EntityFramework is not SQL. What you do in SQL may or may not map directly, or even apply to how you would go about it in EntityFramework. Not only that but when you use EntityFramework you are using EntityFramework *and* C# language features that are not EntityFramework per se, [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for example. Breaking down the problem into its constituent parts can help you solve problems, and make it easier to study up to being able to do more complex operations. Studying and practicing LINQ in isolation will help you be better with EntityFramework.

Comment: I updated this after re-reading your code. I see now that you are trying to return the category a post belongs to, and not a list of posts that belong to a category.

Comment: I changed the names of the database tables to make it more understandable. I am trying to get a list of posts belonging to a category (blog is the category of the posts)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I added a bunch of examples to get you thinking about EntityFramework and LINQ, and hopefully encourage you to take time to study and/or watch some online courses on both technologies.

Comment: Curious how would u do a not in for example I have ids in table I want to exclude from main query but their off different types but both ids and ints?

Comment: @Jeremy Cook: I am looking for a way to send an IEnumerable<int> to LinqToEntities and if it is contained in a link table projected IDs, then return that row, I asked many questions in this site with some answers that no one worked. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: @mz1378 It might help if I could see what you've tried. If you link to an SO question or GitHub repo with more info I'll take a look.

Comment: This Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753983/ef-core-dynamic-linq-comparing-lists-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 6):

LINQ Query

```
from p in _context.Post
where _context.BlogCategory.Any
                ( bc => bc.PostId == p.PostId 
                  && bc.BlogId == &id
                )
select p;
```

SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM Post
WHERE PostId IN (
SELECT PostId FROM BlogCategory
WHERE BlogId = &id);
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM Post p
WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM BlogCategory
      WHERE PostId = p.PostID AND BlogId = &id
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a join for the post to blog relationship and then a where clause as the blog filter.

```
var query = from post in _context.Post
  join blogCat in _context.BlogPost on post.PostId equals blogCat.PostId
  where blogCat.BlogId == blogId
  select post;

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```

This is based on your Sql in the top of your code

```
SELECT * 
FROM Post
WHERE PostId IN (
  SELECT PostId FROM BlogPost WHERE BlogId = &id);
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is exhaustive, this technically answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

You can use `.Select()`

```
 var blog = await _context.Blogs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == blogId);
 var posts = blog ?? blog.BlogCategory.Select(bp => bp.Post);
```

I guess you have navigation property in `Blog` `BlogCategory` 
You may find this helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-latest-nightly-builds-of-ef7)