# How can i find data by field in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
var searchIds = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
var result = persons.Where(p => p.Locations.Any(l => searchIds.Any(id => l.Id == id)));
```

Comment: sorry for my question, what do you mean by "find data by field?" your code above filters persons based on location with the given ids... so what is the question.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266234/entity-framework-core-in-clause-equivalent

Comment: @BagusTesa - his problem is probably that this query doesn't translate to SQL and throws an exception with the latest ef core but he is playing the `guess my error` game so he doesn't want to tell you

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achive. Please provide more details.

Comment: @RandRandom, thats a bit weird, i never thought ef core would fail for simple `any` query as long as its iqueryable. given the link you have provided deals with a separate query that retrieves the actual ids. op didnt provide clear question and trying to clarify things are deemed as rude, perhaps i can play the `guess my error` too at later date. thank you for the help sir.

Comment: @RandRandom Are you sure this doesn't translate into SQL? It looks OK to me.

Comment: @DavidG - nope, not sure at all as my `guess my error` game remark tries to imply, I am basically guessing what the error could be - but I thought that EFCore cant do it since it would need to translate the passed list into `select IN` maybe it can do it - all I know is that if it would fail to generate SQL the newest EFCore throws and exception to warn about client evaluation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        List<int> searchIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<Person> result = persons.Where(p => p.Locations.Any(l => searchIds.Contains(l.Id))).ToList();
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```