# EF core Dynamic Linq comparing Lists in a where clause

Tags: entity-framework-core

I write this code that checks if the list I send contained in table:

```
 if (filterSecondaryConditions != null && filterSecondaryConditions.Count() > 0)
 {
     query = query.Where(w => (w.SecondaryConditions.Select(s => s.Id)
         .Intersect(filterSecondaryConditions)).Count() == filterSecondaryConditions.Count());
 }
```

SecondaryConditions is a Navigation property that goes to a Link Table and I included it as:

```
query = context.Weathers.Include(w => w.SecondaryConditions).AsQueryable();
```

In entity framework core 5 this code does not work (But gives No errors), Is there any working alternatives in ef core 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Ids in your `filterSecondaryConditions` has unique values, you can use the following:

```cs
 if (filterSecondaryConditions != null && filterSecondaryConditions.Count() > 0)
 {
     query = query.Where(w => w.SecondaryConditions.Count(s => filterSecondaryConditions.Contains(s.Id)) 
       == filterSecondaryConditions.Count());
 }
```

Comment: This looks reasonable based on the information provided in the question.

Comment: I was sending IEnumerable<int> as filterSecondaryConditions so it was failing. I converted the filter to List<int> and it is now working.