# Many-to-Many Xref in EFCore Requires Manual Override?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating an application using efcore + sqlite and struggling to get my many-to-many relationships to work as expected. I've been referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-latest-nightly-builds-of-ef7) but seeing some strange behavior when querying against the resulting database

Here's the entities in question:

```
public class Song
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /* Snip Properties */

    public ICollection<SongService> SongServices { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /* Snip Properties */

    public ICollection<SongService> SongServices {get;set;}
}

public class SongService
{
        public int SongId {get;set;}            
        public Song Song {get;set;}

        public int ServiceId {get;set;}            
        public Service Service {get;set;}
}
```

Strangely, EF generated the table as SongService (rather than SongServices) so the queries against SQLite were failing. The table for the other entities were `Songs` and `Services`, though.

[image]

I had to override with

```
[Table("SongServices")]
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? Is it because it's missing an ID so it doesn't know how to 'classify' the table?

**EDIT:**
For reference, this is what my DbContext looks like:

```
public class OnKeyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SongService> SongServices { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SongService>()
            .HasKey(ss => new { ss.ServiceId, ss.SongId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SongService>()
            .HasOne(ss => ss.Song)
            .WithMany(s => s.SongServices)
            .HasForeignKey(ss => ss.SongId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SongService>()
            .HasOne(ss => ss.Service)
            .WithMany(s => s.SongServices)
            .HasForeignKey(ss => ss.ServiceId);
    }
```

Comment: What does your context look like?

Comment: Not sure itll help but I attached as an edit.

Comment: Well everything looks to be good. You can also reference learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model But even according to this your stuff is set up correctly. I can't even recreate this issue. So, I am thinking maybe a bug?

Comment: Interesting, maybe Ill package up the source and post an issue on GH