# Entity Framework Core many-to-many navigation issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core has yet to implement many-to-many relationships, as tracked in GitHub issue [#1368](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1368); however, when I follow the navigation examples in that issue or [similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-latest-nightly-builds-of-ef-core) here at Stack Overflow, my enumeration fails to yield results.

I have a many-to-many relationship between Photos and Tags.

After implementing the join table, examples show I should be able to:

```
var tags = photo.PhotoTags.Select(p => p.Tag);
```

While that yields no results, I am able to to load via:

```
var tags = _context.Photos
    .Where(p => p.Id == 1)
    .SelectMany(p => p.PhotoTags)
    .Select(j => j.Tag)
    .ToList();
```

Relevant code:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhotoTag> PhotoTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhotoTag> PhotoTags { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoTag
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<PhotoTag>().HasKey(x => new { x.PhotoId, x.TagId });
}
```

What am I missing from other examples?

Comment: Maybe try removing the call to base.OnModelCreating ? I have never made that call when overriding OnModelCreating

Comment: Did you tried including `.Include(p => p.PhotoTags)`? EF Core doesn't have lazy loading, so you have to explicit do eager loading via include or or `.Load()`

Comment: @Tseng if you use `PhotoTags.Select(p => p.Tags)`, EF knows that it has to Include PhotoTags, that is not the same as lazy loading

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I know it does it on select (since it's a projection), not sure it does on `SelectMany` though

Comment: @Tseng `SelectMany` is a shortcut for a double `Select` statement, so yes. I have very complex queries with `Select` and `SelectMany` without `Include` calls

Comment: `Select()` fails, whereas `SelectMany()` example works.  Using `Include()` followed by a `ThenInclude()` works, which is ghastly.  Other examples don't show that syntax, instead citing the `Select()` statement.

Comment: @Tseng is right, it depends how you retrieve the `photo` variable. If you retrieve it this way `var photo = _context.Photos.Include(e => e.PhotoTags).ThenInclude(e => e.Tag).FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);`, then later `var tags = photo.PhotoTags.Select(p => p.Tag);` will also work.

Comment: @Ivan - that makes sense, and works - I wonder why such an important note is left out of other citations.  I'll accept that answer.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I guess you have the navigation property inside the select though, like `.Select(new { Tags = p.PhotoTags.Select(pt => pt.Tag).ToList())` or something like that. Now `PhotoTags` is within the select clause, which makes Include unnecessary, since it's a projection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact this is not a specific for `many-to-many` relationship, but in general to the lack of *lazy loading* support in EF Core. So in order to have `Tag` property populated, it has to be eager (or explicitly) loaded. All this is (sort of) explained in the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the EF Core documentation. If you take a look at **Including multiple levels** section, you'll see the following explanation

> You can drill down thru relationships to include multiple levels of related data using the `ThenInclude` method. The following example loads all blogs, their related posts, and the author of each post.

and example for loading the `Post.Author` which is pretty much the same as yours:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ToList();
}
```

So to make this working

```
var tags = photo.PhotoTags.Select(p => p.Tag);
```

the `photo` variable should have been be retrieved using something like this:

```
var photo = _context.Photos
   .Include(e => e.PhotoTags)
       .ThenInclude(e => e.Tag)
   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);
```

Comment: Ahh, I just realized, looking at your answer, that the OP did not start the sentence with `_context`...